# how to create recyclerview with load more and load previous?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i want to create `recyclerview` like given in image. I am not able to figure out a way how to do it. How to create such `recyclerview` or is their any library ?

[image]

i want load previous button also.

Comment: Basically you just need to add the items **to the end** of the current item list **for load more**, and add the items **to the start** of the current item list **for load previous** then call `RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Yes this is good suggestion , but the problem is when i implemented load more button and onclick of it added few more values to my arraylist and passed it to adapter constructor again, but now recyclerview is repeating old values and then i get to see new, For example i wanted to show 1,2,3,4,5 and onclick i wanted to add just 6,7 , but it is becoming like 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: i mean this is happening when i click next button twice